# Is it possible to use a pointer to an uninstantiated object as a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I want an attribute in a C++ class be an uninstantiated class from a particular class heirachy. All members of this class heirachy would then implement the same method, meaning I could instantiate the object and then use the method when the situation calls for it. Here's some code (that doesn't compile) demonstrating what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Event {
public:
    Event() = default;
    virtual void go() = 0;
};

class EventA : Event {
public:
    EventA() = default;

    void go(){
        cout << "Running event A"<< endl;
    }
};

class EventB : Event {
public:
    EventB() = default;


    void go(){
        cout << "Running event B"<< endl;
    }
};

class Situation{
private:
    Event* current_event = &EventA;   //Problematic code: EventA does not refer to a value
public:
    Situation() = default;

    void setEvent(Event* event){
        current_event = event;
    }

    void runEvent(){
        current_event.go();
    }
};

int main() {

    Situation situation;
    situation.runEvent();
    situation.setEvent(&EventB);
    situation.runEvent();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between an object and a type.  C++ types are not objects and do not have addresses.

Comment: You might want to create an instance of an `EventA` that is a static member of class `Situation` and call it `EventStub`, then set `current_event = &EventStub;`

Comment: Okay, this is helpful. So I can't pass classes around like variables to be instantiated and used at a later time. @franji1 Does this work for the polymorphism aspect of this code? I Can use `static EventA eventStub; EventA* current_event = &eventStub;` but not `Event* current_event = &eventStub;`

Comment: Also, `class EventB : Event` is *private inheritance* which means any code outside of the `EventB` class isn't allowed to know that EventB inherits from Event. Use `class EventB : public Event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two places, you seem to be doing what could be described as trying to take a pointer from a type:

```
Event* current_event = &EventA;
```

and

```
situation.setEvent(&EventB);
```

This doesn't work and is not really a thing with proper meaning in C++. What you are trying to do could be implemented in 3 different ways I can think of.

Method 1: instead of having a class, you can have a function pointer, and pass the function pointer as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void eventA_go(){
    cout << "Running event A"<< endl;
}

void eventB_go(){
    cout << "Running event B"<< endl;
}

class Situation{
private:
    using EventFunctionPtr = void (*)();
    EventFunctionPtr current_event = &eventA_go;
public:
    Situation() = default;

    void setEvent(EventFunctionPtr event){
        current_event = event;
    }

    void runEvent(){
        current_event();
    }
};

int main() {

    Situation situation;
    situation.runEvent();
    situation.setEvent(&eventB_go);
    situation.runEvent();

    return 0;
};
```

Method 2: you can make this code a little more generic, by allowing any type of callable in your `Situation` class, not only function pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void eventA_go(){
    cout << "Running event A"<< endl;
}

void eventB_go(){
    cout << "Running event B"<< endl;
}

class Situation{
private:
    std::function<void ()> current_event = eventA_go;
public:
    Situation() = default;

    template <typename F>
    void setEvent(F&& event){
        current_event = event;
    }

    void runEvent(){
        current_event();
    }
};

int main() {

    Situation situation;
    situation.runEvent();
    situation.setEvent(&eventB_go);
    situation.runEvent();

    return 0;
};
```

Method 3: you can go back to your original idea of having a base class that must be implemented to provide a `go()` method, but in this case you will actually have to make sure the objects you are calling do exists. A possible way to do it is with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Event {
public:
    Event() = default;
    virtual ~Event() = default;
    virtual void go() = 0;
};

class EventA : public Event {
public:
    EventA() = default;

    void go(){
        cout << "Running event A"<< endl;
    }
};

class EventB : public Event {
public:
    EventB() = default;

    void go(){
        cout << "Running event B"<< endl;
    }
};

class Situation{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Event> current_event = std::make_unique<EventA>();
public:
    Situation() = default;

    void setEvent(std::unique_ptr<Event>&& event){
        current_event = std::move(event);
    }

    void runEvent(){
        current_event->go();
    }
};

int main() {

    Situation situation;
    situation.runEvent();
    situation.setEvent(std::make_unique<EventB>());
    situation.runEvent();

    return 0;
};
```

Notice that, in this case, the destructor of the abstract class must be `virtual`, and the inheritance must be public.

Comment: Hi @lvella, very useful indeed, thanks. A quick remark on method 1, presumably it would also be possible to group `eventA_go` and `eventB_go` into a class and then pass `EventFunctionPtr = <NameOfClass>::eventA_go`, rather than having lots of top level ungrouped functions?

Comment: Only if they were static methods, and there would be no need for them to inherit from a common base class.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot form pointers to classes, and you cannot invoke [non-static] member functions without a class instance (object).

You should probably `std::make_unique` an instance of the type you want to use.

Don't forget to give your base a virtual destructor, since you're doing polymorphism things.

A static alternative would be `std::variant`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about classes and variables. Which object would `situation.runEvent();` run on? I think you want to *publicly* derive the classes from `Event` and initialize `current_event` when you need to. You don't need to do anything like `current_event = &EventB`. C++ automagically determines which function is needed to be called based on what `current_event` is dynamically pointing to. Here's what I think you meant to do:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class Event {
 public:
  virtual void go() = 0;
  virtual ~Event() = default;  // Don't forget the virtual destructor
};

class EventA : public Event {
 public:
  void go() override { std::cout << "Running event A" << std::endl; }
};

class EventB : public Event {
 public:
  void go() override { std::cout << "Running event B" << std::endl; }
};

class Situation {
 private:
  Event* current_event = nullptr;

 public:
  void setEvent(Event* event) { current_event = event; }

  void runEvent() {
    assert(current_event);
    current_event->go();
  }
};

int main() {
  Situation situation;
  EventA a;
  EventB b;
  situation.setEvent(&a);
  situation.runEvent();
  situation.setEvent(&b);
  situation.runEvent();
}
```

Comment: Spot on, I was overcomplicating things. Thanks.